# How to use sed command to replace hostname and ip adddress

Tags: linux

I am using `sed` command to replace the IP Address of Host from a file where IP is generating randomly. I am not getting a search pattern for a double quote(`"`). below pattern have to replace:

`Host1 = "1.1.1.1"` replace with `Host2="2.2.2.2"` where Host1's IP address is not fixed.

I was trying to replace the below file:

```
cat a.txt
Host1 ="1.1.1.1"

sed -i -e 's/Host1 =*/Host =2.2.2.2/g' a.txt

cat a.txt
Host =2.2.2.2"1.1.1.1"
```

Comment: Please post an example of the output of the file you are trying to change the IP address from.

Comment: I was trying to replace the below file
 cat a.txt Host1 ="1.1.1.1"

sed -i -e 's/Host1 =*/Host =2.2.2.2/g' a.txt

cat a.txt Host =2.2.2.2"1.1.1.1"

Comment: How to replace 1.1.1.1

Comment: Please clarify, are you trying to replace "1.1.1.1" in a specific line or are you trying to replace any IP in a specific line or any IP in any line or...?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `1.1.1.1` by running this command, using `sed` too:

```
sed -i 's|"[^"]*"|"2.2.2.2"|' < a.txt
```

That way the IP address will change to `2.2.2.2` no matter what IP address it was before, as long as it is stored between double quotes (`"`) in your file.